# How to expose kubernetes nginx-ingress service on public node IP at port 80 / 443?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I installed `ingress-nginx` in a cluster. I tried exposing the service with the `kind: nodePort` option, but this only allows for a port range between `30000-32767` (AFAIK)... I need to expose the service at port `80` for http and `443` for tls, so that I can link `A Records` for the domains directly to the service. Does anyone know how this can be done?

I tried with `type: LoadBalancer` before, which worked fine, but this creates a new external Load Balancer at my cloud provider for each cluster. In my current situation I want to spawn multiple mini clusters. It would be too expensive to create a new (digitalocean) Load Balalancer for each of those, so I decided to run each cluster with it's own internal ingress-controller and expose that directly on `80/443`.

Comment: hi, If you want to expose it publicly use `type: LoadBalancer`. Here is the [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer).

Comment: What does "kubectl get ingresses" tell?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi See updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want on IP for 80 port from a service you could use the externalIP field in service config yaml. You could find how to write the yaml here
[Kubernetes External IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips)

But if your usecase is really like getting the ingress controller up and running it does not need the service to be exposed externally.

Comment: I think `externalIPs` is exactly like what I'm looking for. Could you please elaborate on the second part of your answer? If it's not exposed externally, how do I expose the ingresses to the public then?

Comment: Ok So i mean to say if you are looking for bringing up an ingress controller for a kubernetes cluster https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/  then it does not need the service to be exposed outside it should be enough to have the node IPs which is exposed publicly.

Answer (score 3):

if you are on bare metal so change your ingress-controller service type to `NodePort` and add a reverse proxy to flow traffic to your ingress-controller service with selected `NodePort`.

As [@Pramod V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9581141/pramod-v) answerd if you use `externalIP` in ingress-controller service so you loose real remote address in your EndPoints.

A more complete answer could be found [Here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/)